# sum of 1 column 2 results diff where per result! so simple yet not working

Tags: mysql, sum, union, case, where-clause

ok this is very simple yet have been searching for 3 hours and still cant get it to work!

the scenario is i have a db with individual costs of 2 business' and i want to sum the cost of each business and present on screen. now i know this is simple enough and easily done with two SELECTS. but i want to do this in one query!

DB

```
|cost|business|
|100 |   1    |
|200 |   2    |
|200 |   1    |
|300 |   2    |
```

so from the table above we know that b1 = 300 and b2 = 500! but none of my queries work!

i have tried UNION and CASE but am unfamiliar with them.
my queries:

first try:

```
$buscost = mysql_query("SELECT FORMAT(sum(`cost`),2) as `b1` FROM `outgoing` WHERE `business`=1 
UNION 
SELECT FORMAT(sum(`cost`),2) as `b2` FROM `outgoing` WHERE `business`=2")
or die(mysql_error());
    $buscost = mysql_fetch_array($busowe);
```

second try:

```
$buscost = mysql_query("SELECT 
CASE WHEN `business` = 1 THEN FORMAT(sum(`cost`),2) END AS `b1` ,
CASE WHEN `business` = 2 THEN FORMAT(sum(`cost`),2) END AS `b2`  
FROM `outgoing` WHERE `active`='yes' ");
$buscost = mysql_fetch_array($buscost);
```

*cost is set as float(11,2).

im sure im close i just dont know enough to figure it out, have found similar questions on here but none of the answers helped!

oh and if i `print_r`, the first only fetches the sum of b1, b2 doesnt exist! and
the second array all i get is the result set of the first case and case 2 "b2" is empty,but exists!! i have checked the tables and there is test data in there for both business'.

please help any advice or a solution is greatly appreciated.

edit:forgot to mention all results will also need to be filtered with where `active`='yes'

Comment: thanks to jcho360 and specially dalen for answering and editing a few times tried the union one but it failed again but i finally used **`SELECT
(
   SELECT FORMAT(sum(cost),2) as b1
   FROM outgoing
   WHERE business=1 AND active = 'yes'
   GROUP BY business
) AS b1,
(
   SELECT FORMAT(sum(cost),2) as b1
   FROM outgoing
   WHERE business=2 AND active = 'yes'
   GROUP BY business
) AS b2`** and works perfect.. THANKS FOR THE QUICK ANSWERS GUYS MUCH APPRECIATED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youn need to group by:

```
SELECT business, FORMAT(sum(`cost`),2) AS cost
FROM outgoing
WHERE active = 'yes'
GROUP BY business
```

if you want the format:

```
business | cost
b1       | 300
b2       | 500
```

or

```
SELECT
(
   SELECT FORMAT(sum(`cost`),2) as `b1`
   FROM `outgoing`
   WHERE `business`=1 AND active = 'yes'
   GROUP BY business
) AS b1,
(
   SELECT FORMAT(sum(`cost`),2) as `b1`
   FROM `outgoing`
   WHERE `business`=2 AND active = 'yes'
   GROUP BY business
) AS b2
```

if you need the format

```
b1 | b2
300| 500
```

Comment: thanks dude, just what i needed. although your top query only resulted in the first set being summed! but the second is spot on

Comment: there was a mistake on the first query,it is now adjusted

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  business, SUM(cost)
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        business
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT business, SUM(cost) AS totalCost FROM myTable GROUP BY business
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
     select

 @num1:=(select sum(actor_id) from actor where actor_id%2=0)as number_1, 

@num2:=(select sum(actor_id) from actor where actor_id%2!=0)as number_2,

@num1+@num2 as TOTAL;
```

or if you need active.

```
     select

 @num1:=(select sum(actor_id) from actor where actor_id%2=0 and  active='yes')as number_1, 

@num2:=(select sum(actor_id) from actor where actor_id%2!=0 and  active='yes')as number_2,

@num1+@num2 as TOTAL;
```

Comment: thanks, nice edit adding the TOTAL aswell think i can get rid of the other query too now.